# Add a view on top of a UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, overlay, addsubview

I want to add a view on top of a custom segmented control. Below is my code.

```
import UIKit

class CustomSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let overlayView = UIView(frame: frame)
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        superview?.addSubview(overlayView)
    }
}
```

But strangely it doesn't overlay the segmented control properly.

[image]

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It obviously does overlay the segmented control, so why do you say it doesn't? And why do you want to cover the segmented control with a yellow rectangle anyway?

Comment: What's the x/y position of the cute yellow rectangle? Perhaps instead of using self.frame, create a new frame with x:0 y:0 width:frame.size.width height:frame.size.height

Comment: `UIView(frame: bounds)`

Comment: @MikePollard & Spoek: I tried both ways but they yield the same [result](http://i.imgur.com/Ce1ShAe.png). Adding it to a subview like this `addSubview(overlayView)` looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/LMFoeYb.png) which is not how I want it though.

Comment: @matt I need to add some subviews to the segmented control but there's a strange behavior which obscures the subview when the a segment is selected. So I add a overlay view and add those subviews to that. I'm going to make the background color to clear color. Just using yellow until I get the position right.